# MS Access : Average and Total Calculation in Single Query

Tags: database, ms-access

**INTRODUCTION TO DATABASE TABLE BEING USED -**

I am working on a “Stock Market Prices” based Database Table. My table has got the data for the following FIELDS –

ID
SYMBOL
OPEN
HIGH
LOW
CLOSE
VOLUME
VOLUME CHANGE
VOLUME CHANGE %
OPEN_INT
SECTOR
TIMESTAMP

New data gets added to the table daily “Monday to Friday”, based on the stock market price changes for that day. The current requirement is based on the `VOLUME` field, which shows the volume traded for a particular stock on daily basis.

**REQUIREMENT –**
To get the Average and Total Volume for last 10,15 and 30 Days respectively.

**METHOD USED CURRENTLY -**
I created these 9 SEPARATE QUERIES in order to get my desired results –
First I have created these 3 queries to take out the most recent last 10,15 and 30 dates from the current table:

qryLast10DaysStored
  qryLast15DaysStored
  qryLast30DaysStored

Then I have created these 3 queries for getting the respective AVERAGES:

qrySymbolAvgVolume10Days
  qrySymbolAvgVolume15Days
  qrySymbolAvgVolume30Days

And then I have created these 3 queries for getting the respective TOTALS:

qrySymbolTotalVolume10Days
  qrySymbolTotalVolume15Days
  qrySymbolTotalVolume30Days

**PROBLEM BEING FACED WITH CURRENT METHOD -**
Now, my problem is that I have ended up having these so many different queries, whereas I wanted to get the output into One Single Query, **as shown in the Snapshot of the Excel Sheet:**

http://i49.tinypic.com/256tgcp.png

**SOLUTION NEEDED -**
Is there some way by which I can get these required fields into ONE SINGLE QUERY, so that I do not have to look into multiple places for the required fields? Can someone please tell me how to get all these separate queries into one -
A) Either by taking out or moving the results from these separate individual queries to one.
B) **Or by making a new query which calculates all these fields within itself, so that these separate individual queries are no longer needed. This would be a better solution I think.**

**One Clarification about Dates –**
Some friend might think why I used the method of using Top 10,15 and 30 for getting the last 10,15 and 30 Date Values. Why not I just used the PC Date for getting these values? Or used something like -

```
("VOLUME","tbl-B", "TimeStamp BETWEEN Date() - 10 AND Date()")
```

The answer is that I require my query to "Read" the date from the "TIMESTAMP" Field, and then perform its calculations accordingly **for  LAST / MOST RECENT "10 days, 15 days, 30 days”  FOR WHICH THE DATA IS AVAILABLE IN THE TABLE, WITHOUT BOTHERING WHAT THE CURRENT DATE IS. It should not depend upon the current date in any way.**

**If there is any better method  or more efficient way to create these queries, then please enlighten.**

Comment: I don't understand the date part. If you do Top(10) and you do an order by your date field. Would it work? You would get the last 10 date

Comment: you have to perform calculation based on the last 10, 15, 30 days in list? so datediff could be more than 10, 15 and 30? and last days for each symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access doesn't support most advanced SQL syntax and clauses, so this is a bit of a hack, but it works, and is fast on your small sample.  You're basically running 3 queries but the Union clauses allow you to combine into one:

```
select
   Symbol,
   sum([10DayTotalVol]) as 10DayTotalV,
   sum([10DayAvgVol]) as 10DayAvgV,
   sum([15DayTotalVol]) as 15DayTotalV,
   sum([15DayAvgVol]) as 15DayAvgV,
   sum([30DayTotalVol]) as 30DayTotalV,
   sum([30DayAvgVol]) as 30DayAvgV

from (

      select
        Symbol, 
        sum(volume) as 10DayTotalVol, avg(volume) as 10DayAvgVol,
        0 as 15DayTotalVol, 0 as 15DayAvgVol,
        0 as 30DayTotalVol, 0 as 30DayAvgVol
      from
         [tbl-b]
      where
         timestamp >= (select min(ts) from (select distinct top 10 timestamp as ts from [tbl-b] order by timestamp desc ))
      group by
         Symbol   

      UNION

      select
        Symbol, 
        0, 0,
        sum(volume), avg(volume),
        0, 0
      from
         [tbl-b]
      where
         timestamp >= (select min(ts) from (select distinct top 15 timestamp as ts from [tbl-b] order by timestamp desc ))
      group by
         Symbol    

      UNION

      select
        Symbol, 
        0, 0,
        0, 0,
        sum(volume), avg(volume)
      from
         [tbl-b]
      where
         timestamp >= (select min(ts) from (select distinct top 30 timestamp as ts from [tbl-b] order by timestamp desc ))
      group by
         Symbol 
      ) s

group by 
   Symbol
```

Comment: This code Rocks !! Just one query to get all the required fields, no more messing around with multiple queries. Excellent Stuff ExactBox. Your method is Brilliant.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You have separate queries to compute `10DayTotalVolume` and `10DayAvgVolume`.  I suspect you can compute both in one query, *qry10DayVolumes*.

```
SELECT
    b.SYMBOL,
    Sum(b.VOLUME) AS 10DayTotalVolume,
    Avg(b.VOLUME) AS 10DayAvgVolume
FROM
    [tbl-B] AS b INNER JOIN
    qryLast10DaysStored AS q
    ON b.TIMESTAMP = q.TIMESTAMP
GROUP BY b.SYMBOL;
```

However, that makes me wonder whether `10DayAvgVolume` can ever be anything other than `10DayTotalVolume / 10`

Similar considerations apply to the 15 and 30 day values.

Ultimately, I think you want something based on a starting point like this:

```
SELECT
    q10.SYMBOL,
    q10.[10DayTotalVolume],
    q10.[10DayAvgVolume],
    q15.[15DayTotalVolume],
    q15.[15DayAvgVolume],
    q30.[30DayTotalVolume],
    q30.[30DayAvgVolume]
FROM
    (qry10DayVolumes AS q10
    INNER JOIN qry15DayVolumes AS q15
    ON q10.SYMBOL = q15.SYMBOL)
    INNER JOIN qry30DayVolumes AS q30
    ON q10.SYMBOL = q30.SYMBOL;
```

That assumes you have created `qry15DayVolumes` and `qry30DayVolumes` following the approach I suggested for `qry10DayVolumes`.

If you want to cut down the number of queries, you could use subqueries for each of the `qry??DayVolumes` saved queries, but try it this way first to make sure the logic is correct.

In that second query above, there can be a problem due to field names which start with digits.  Enclose those names in square brackets or re-alias them in `qry10DayVolumes`, `qry15DayVolumes`, and `qry30DayVolumes` using alias names which begin with letters instead of digits.

I tested the query as written above with the "*2nd Upload.mdb*" you uploaded, and it ran without error from Access 2007.  Here is the first row of the result set from that query:

```
SYMBOL 10DayTotalVolume 10DayAvgVolume 15DayTotalVolume 15DayAvgVolume   30DayTotalVolume 30DayAvgVolume
ACC-1             42909         4290.9            54892 3659.46666666667            89669 2988.96666666667
```

Comment: i tried other solutions also but i think you can't do much better than this...i wanted to make everything fit in a single query, and using DSUM it is possible, but it's far from being SQL standard, it looks awful, and it's slow!!

Comment: @HansUp thank you so much for the excellent idea. Now I find it funny why I myself did not get this idea earlier about doing the average and total within same query rather then doing them separately !

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The above code is working fine now. And it is showing the required fields correctly. Thanks a lot for the help.